# Unable to parse file with jQuery in IE 8 and below because it's not XML (even though it sort of is XML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, kml

I'm using AJAX to load in a KML file (which is basically an XML file).  I'm able to parse everything fine in IE9, FF, etc., but in IE8 it doesn't work.  I get the data back but I'm not able to parse it in jQuery.  I'm assuming this is because it's not being acknowledged as true XML.
If I change the file from us_states.kml to us_states.xml, for example, it works fine.
So, I COULD try to have people change their files from kml to xml manually, but I'd prefer being able to read it in and have it work on all browsers, old and new.
Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: KMLFile,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "XML",
                    success: function(data){ ...}
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hmm... Have you tried retrieving it as plain text and then parsing as xml with `$.parseXML(xmltext)`?

Comment: Yes, and it fails with no error message.  THe XML is well formed and the data is plain text so I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd skip the XML/KML issue completely and go straight to JSON:

http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/JsonObjects

Comment: I looked into geoXML, and it is awesome, but a bit more than what I need at this point.  Down the road I'll probably end up using it though.

Comment: Parsing JSON is 100x faster than parsing XML, it may be worth it.

Comment: it's tough finding a simple example of how to do it.  I'm not using it for google maps, and the only tutorial I can find is for integration with google.  Maybe I'll mess with it and give it a shot.

Comment: The problem with geoXML3 is that appears you need to include the google maps api to even parse the KML.  I'm looking to use this data for OpenLayers.